# Iterative calculation of Entropy increase when Bottle A charges Bottle B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I’m doing a classical problem in an iterative manner on a spreadsheet. This is a trial for a more complicated study.  As shown in Figure 1,  at each opening of the valve,  0.0784 Kg of air (denoted as Mpac)  passes from Bottle A into Bottle B.  At each iteration the properties (P (Pa),T (K) & M (Kg) ) of both bottles are calculated.  After 57 iterations the pressures are equal as shown.  The final mixing is done “closed form” and final results  reasonably duplicate results of the classical problem.  Figure 2 shows the iterative equations.  However, I cannot duplicate entropy increase using this iterative approach.  To duplicate the classical “closed form” solution for entropy increase for Bottle B,  I used dS=(dU + VdP)/T instead of dS=(dU-VdP)/T. Get the same error if I use dH.  I would like to know if my iterative approach makes thermodynamic sense, and how would one iteratively calculate entropy

[image: System under evaluation]

[image: iteration calculations]

Comment: I don't understand why you calculated the entropy change the way you did.  Why didn't you just subtract the initial entropy from the final entropy?  Also, you seem to have omitted the flow of entropy from the first tank to the second.

Comment: For Chet Miller- I used air tables to get the "proper" answer, but how do you calculate entropy at each iteration?  Could use air tables, but that would be very laborious for 59 iterations.

Comment: Do you know the equation for molar entropy of an ideal gas as a function of temperature and pressure?

Comment: No, I do not know

Comment: $$s(T,P)=s(T_{ref},P_{ref|}+C_p\ln{(T/T_{ref})}-R\ln{(P/P_{ref})}$$where ref refers to an arbitrary reference state.

Comment: For Chet Miller- Thank you- When I included the iterative entropy flow (Mpac) from TankA to TankB, the  overall entropy change was  1.735 kJ/K.  This is similar to the closed form solution of 1.85 kJ/K.